# How do I convert an SQL query that contains INNER LOOP JOIN to LINQ?

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

I am unable to convert below query to LINQ. The clause `INNER LOOP JOIN` is not able to convert to LINQ a query.

SQL Query :

```
SELECT
    b.tm_runManagerID,
    b.testName,
    b.startDate,
    b.endDate,
    SUM( CASE WHEN c.testPass = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS passNumber,
    SUM( CASE WHEN c.testPass = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS failNumber,
    SUM(1) AS totalNumber,
    b.status
FROM dbo.tm_actionManager a WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER LOOP JOIN [tm_runManager] b WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.tm_runManagerID = b.tm_runManagerID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tm_testResult c WITH (NOLOCK) 
    on a.tm_actionManagerID = c.tm_actionManagerID AND c.nodeCompared = 'overallresult'
    WHERE   a.tm_runManagerID IN (SELECT tm_runManagerID FROM dbo.tm_runManager (NOLOCK) WHERE isActive = 1)
    GROUP BY b.tm_runManagerID,b.testName,b.startDate,b.endDate,b.status
    ORDER BY b.tm_runManagerID DESC
```

Comment: Ignore the LOOP keyword. It is a HINT which is not supported in LINQ.

Comment: Please never just post SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, tell what type of LINQ you're targeting (to entities?), *and* show your own first efforts. They clarify more to us than you might think.

Answer (score 2):

`LOOP`, `HASH` and `MERGE` are joins **hints**. It specifies that the `JOIN` in the query should use looping, hashing, or merging. It is only a hint so that the database can optimize the query, and are normally not used except in rare cases where the automatic optimization is not enough.

For that reason, there is no translation into LINQ. Most of the times, since your SQL code will be different anyway, you can safely ignore it.